# Getting accurate file size in megabytes?

Tags: ruby

How can I get the accurate file size in MB? I tried this:

```
compressed_file_size = File.size("Compressed/#{project}.tar.bz2") / 1024000

puts "file size is #{compressed_file_size} MB"
```

But it chopped the 0.9 and showed 2 MB instead of 2.9 MB

Comment: separate from the float vs int problem - is 1024000 really the constant you want? Usually MB is 2^20, which is 1048576.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I fixed that in my code.

Comment: Depending on how fully-featured you want this, the source for Rails' `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper#number_to_human_size` is a good reference implementation. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_human_size

Comment: Know this is old, but what is happening is you are dividing by an integer, which returns integers, aka. chops the number. If you add a `.0` at the end it will calculate with floating point. So: `compressed_file_size = ... .... / 1024000.0` should give you floating point number. You might possibly need to add a `.to_f` on the `File.size(...)`.

Comment: I'm not sure using `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_human_size` also answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026048/pretty-file-size-in-ruby/78207667#78207667

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

```
compressed_file_size = File.size("Compressed/#{project}.tar.bz2").to_f / 2**20
formatted_file_size = '%.2f' % compressed_file_size
```

One-liner:

```
compressed_file_size = '%.2f' % (File.size("Compressed/#{project}.tar.bz2").to_f / 2**20)
```

or:

```
compressed_file_size = (File.size("Compressed/#{project}.tar.bz2").to_f / 2**20).round(2)
```

---

Further information on **`%`-operator of String:**
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/String.html#M000207

---

BTW: I prefer "MiB" instead of "MB" if I use base2 calculations (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)

Answer (score 10):

You're doing integer division (which drops the fractional part).   Try dividing by 1024000.0 so ruby knows you want to do floating point math.

Comment: I don't even use Ruby and that was exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: This too. It's giving me 2.8679921875 MB I just want 2.86 MB

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
compressed_file_size = File.size("Compressed/#{project}.tar.bz2").to_f / 1024000
```

Comment: That's giving me 2.8679921875 MB I just want 2.86 MB

Comment: You can use compressed_file_size.round(2) or '.2f' % compressed_file_size on output

Comment: I didn't get '.2f' % compressed_file_size on output. Please clarify.

Comment: puts "file size is #{'.2f' % compressed_file_size} MB"

Comment: Try: `formatted_file_size = '%.2f' % compressed_file_size` -- there was a "%" missing in the format string. Further information on `%`-operator of String: (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/String.html#M000207)

Answer (score 1):

You might find a formatting function useful ([pretty print file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026048/pretty-file-size-in-ruby)), and here is my example,

```
def format_mb(size)
  conv = [ 'b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb', 'pb', 'eb' ];
  scale = 1024;

  ndx=1
  if( size < 2*(scale**ndx)  ) then
    return "#{(size)} #{conv[ndx-1]}"
  end
  size=size.to_f
  [2,3,4,5,6,7].each do |ndx|
    if( size < 2*(scale**ndx)  ) then
      return "#{'%.3f' % (size/(scale**(ndx-1)))} #{conv[ndx-1]}"
    end
  end
  ndx=7
  return "#{'%.3f' % (size/(scale**(ndx-1)))} #{conv[ndx-1]}"
end
```

Test it out,

```
tries = [ 1,2,3,500,1000,1024,3000,99999,999999,999999999,9999999999,999999999999,99999999999999,3333333333333333,555555555555555555555]

tries.each { |x|
  print "size #{x} -> #{format_mb(x)}\n"
}
```

Which produces,

```
size 1 -> 1 b
size 2 -> 2 b
size 3 -> 3 b
size 500 -> 500 b
size 1000 -> 1000 b
size 1024 -> 1024 b
size 3000 -> 2.930 kb
size 99999 -> 97.655 kb
size 999999 -> 976.562 kb
size 999999999 -> 953.674 mb
size 9999999999 -> 9.313 gb
size 999999999999 -> 931.323 gb
size 99999999999999 -> 90.949 tb
size 3333333333333333 -> 2.961 pb
size 555555555555555555555 -> 481.868 eb
```