# Convert human readable file size to bytes in ruby

Tags: ruby, byte, filesize

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026048/pretty-file-size-in-ruby). My requirement is the exact reverse of this. Example a string 10KB needs to be converted to 10240 (its equivalent byte size). Do we have any gem for this? or inbuilt method in ruby? I did my research, I wasn't able to spot it

Comment: Which units do you have to convert?

Comment: Commonly used units of filesize, B, KB, MB, GB

Comment: I don't know any gem for this but you can probably parse a `number unit` pattern and perform the conversion yourself. Shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [filesize](https://github.com/dominikh/filesize) ([rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/filesize/versions/0.1.1))

It's quite trivial to write your own:

```
module ToBytes
  def to_bytes
    md = match(/^(?<num>\d+)\s?(?<unit>\w+)?$/)
    md[:num].to_i * 
      case md[:unit]
      when 'KB'
        1024
      when 'MB'
        1024**2
      when 'GB'
        1024**3
      when 'TB'
        1024**4
      when 'PB'
        1024**5
      when 'EB'
        1024**6
      when 'ZB'
        1024**7
      when 'YB'
        1024**8
      else
        1
      end
  end
end

size_string = "10KB"
size_string.extend(ToBytes).to_bytes
=> 10240

String.include(ToBytes)
"1024 KB".to_bytes
=> 1048576
```

If you need `KiB`, `MiB` etc then you just add multipliers.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method using `while`:

```
def number_format(n)
   n2, n3 = n, 0
   while n2 >= 1e3
      n2 /= 1e3
      n3 += 1
   end
   return '%.3f' % n2 + ['', ' k', ' M', ' G'][n3]
end

s = number_format(9012345678)
puts s == '9.012 G'
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop